# How to include a module in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, reactphp

I am trying to use ReactPHP in a Laravel 5.5 installation.  In a non-laravel project it works fine. I've copied this library to

```
DOCUMENT_ROOT/vendor/react
```

The class I'm trying to load is `DOCUMENT_ROOT/vendor/react/event-loop/src/Factory.php`

I am using absolute referencing rather than using name-spaces - so in my class that uses React I have:

```
$loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
```

Laravel is complaining with:

> Class 'React\EventLoop\Factory' not found

How can I get it to load, and is the `vendor` directory the right place to put it?

Comment: try to use this "laravel-wrapper":
https://packagist.org/packages/mnvx/laravel-reactphp
(in laravel environemnt is important to use `composer` package manager to "manipulate" vendor directory)

Comment: It's what I hate about Laravel.  What drove me to PHP and away from C/C++/Java was the simplicity of the environment.  All these layers have really taken the joy out of the development process (for me).

Comment: maybe there is some workaround - however I always use composer. Every body use it...

Comment: Composer is solution for so called `dependency hell` problem - if you will heve more experience and wider perspective then you will appreciate this tool.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski, since you were the first to answer, you should turn your comment into an answer -- I followed your advice and now on to the next dependency

Comment: I create answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this [laravel-wrapper](http://packagist.org/packages/mnvx/laravel-reactphp) (in laravel environemnt is important to use composer package manager to "manipulate" vendor directory)

Composer is solution for so called `dependency hell` problem - everybody who have more experience and wider perspective appreciate this tool.

Comment: Thanks that solved my React dependency, now on to Ratchet which requires a PECL module.  I "get it", I just hate it. As I noted before I may end up just keeping this module outside of Laravel as it all works fine in a native PHP implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Hey ReactPHP core developer here. The recommended way to user our packages is to user composer, the following installs our meta package installing all our packages:

```
composer require react/react
```

How ever it is considered best practice to install the specific packages you need. For example when you want to use our HTTP server you can install it with the following command:

```
composer require react/http
```

What are you trying to achieve with ReactPHP?

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate the effort.  I'm trying to  satisfy a library requirement that gets ongoing live data from a service I use. The reactphp library worked great and without additional work on my part until I tried to integrate it into laravel.  Now just having to work through the dependencies... Thanks

Comment: My suggestion is to read up on [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) and use that to install the requried reactphp packages. It will [manage](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md) all your dependencies in vendor with the [composer.json](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md) file.  Infect your laravel project should already have a `composer.json` in its root directory. Running one of the `composer` commands from above should resolve your autoloading issue.

Comment: Yes I followed the advice from KamilKiełczewski and now on to the next dependency, which has further dependencies  that appear to fail for PHP 7.0 (requiring a PECL module) - but I'll take that issue to new question.  I might just let this service run outside Laravel - I much prefer programming my solution, and not  wasting my time on all these configuration issues.